# Как не "переполнять" input?

Tags: html, input

[image]

Как избежать подобного? 
Хотелось бы, чтобы новые цифры были вплотную к правой грани, а старые скрывались слева?

Comment: Желаемое вами поведение и есть стандартное поведение input. Если у вас не так, значит вы сами что-то сломали. Значит покажите пример, где как и почему у вас не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое решение - это изменить направление текста:

```css
input {
  text-align: right;
}

input:not(:focus) {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```